# How can I overlay a search bar over MapKit?

Tags: ios, user-interface, overlay, mapkit, user-experience

**How can I overlay a search bar over MapKit?**

I like how the new Google Maps application has a search box and buttons that hover over the map.

See the image on the left:

[image: The left-most image shows what I mean.]

I'm not sure how to get this however as I have not been programming iOS for longer than a couple of weeks. Any ideas on how I could hover UI elements on top of each other with Storyboards/Objective-C?

Presumably it's a navigation bar that has been made invisible but how is this done, and how is it the Map appears underneath it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search box appears to be a custom control which mimics behavior of a UISearchBar and which would inherit from UIControl. Since UIControl inherits from UIView, you can add it to your map view

1. programatically with the addSubview: method
2. via Storyboard by adding your custom control to your map in the appropriate view controller